# When I run ng build --prod, I get "Error: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, webpack

I get this strange error when I run `ng build --prod`

`Error: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined`

There is no stack trace and no other clues.
However I have looked into the error log files and have found that the error happens in a file called `ExternalModuleFactory.js` here

```
    /**
     * @param {NormalModuleFactory} normalModuleFactory the normal module factory
     * @returns {void}
     */
    apply(normalModuleFactory) {
        const globalType = this.type;
    const factorized = normalModuleFactory.hooks.factorize;
    factorized.tapAsync(
            "ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin",
            (data, callback) => {
                const context = data.context;
                const dependency = data.dependencies[0];
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and/or at least how to debug this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working by uninstalling `webpack 5.11` and installing `npm install webpack@4`

Comment: You should accept your answer, that was the right fix for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin* is [invoking](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L17) [getHooks](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L17)  HtmlWebpack [Plugin during compilation](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L17)[method of](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L17)

This method is only available in version. [4 and up of HtmlWebpackPlugin.](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/index.js#L1017)

This is why [the documentation recommends](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin#inline-source-extension-for-the-html-webpack-plugin) to use this version and up.

You can get this version by installing [html-webpack-plugin@next](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#install-beta)

Comment: Where do you see `HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin`?

Comment: I have update Answer Please check @CodyBugstein

Comment: Weird because it didn't work on version 5+